# Can an ordinary 9x9 sudoku have only 17 clues AND an empty row or column?

Tags: sudoku

As far as I know an ordinary 9x9 sudoku must initially have 17 clues minimun. Can theese 17 clues be in any position (even if that means to have an empty row or column)? Or must it be at least 1 clue per row and column?

I have no idea on how to find the answer so it would be great if anybody knew it or knew some method I can use to find it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @trincot, they ask for the position of these 17 clues, so I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: I will update the title.

Comment: Good one, I was thrown off too initially by the title

Comment: Sorry if the title wasn't clear enough and thank you for writing it better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible with an empty row/column, I just clicked through some examples and found the following sudoku: http://sudoku99.com/sudoku9x9/20_level_17_hint/?722581

I checked and it's indeed a solvable sudoku. Hope this helps :)

Comment: It does help indeed. Thank you a lot, I've been looking for examples but couldn't find any so this is really helpful :)

Comment: Happy to hear that! I stumbled on this one after only ten tries I think, but interesting question! I'm curious how far you can push this, but don't have enough time to think about it more deeply haha, if you end up finding some stronger result, I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 47158 essentially different 17-clue Sudoku (one place you can find them is here: https://github.com/t-dillon/tdoku/blob/master/data.zip), so you can just count how many have various combinations of empty rows, columns, and boxes. Here's an example in awk.

```
cat puzzles2_17_clue \
| grep -v '#' \
| tr . '#' \
| awk '
/^#########/ { r += 1 }
/^.........#########/ { r += 1 }
/^..................#########/ { r += 1 }
/^...........................#########/ { r += 1 }
/^....................................#########/ { r += 1 }
/^.............................................#########/ { r += 1 }
/^......................................................#########/ { r += 1 }
/^...............................................................#########/ { r += 1 }
/^........................................................................#########/ { r += 1 }
/^#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^.#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^..#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^...#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^....#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^.....#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^......#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^.......#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#........#/ { c += 1 }
/^###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/^...###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/^......###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/^...........................###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/^..............................###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/^.................................###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/^......................................................###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/^.........................................................###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/^............................................................###......###......###/ { b += 1 }
/./ { print r,c,b; r=0; c=0; b=0 }' \
| sort \
| uniq -c
```

And you get:

```
        r c b
  14756 0 0 0
   2117 0 0 1
     57 0 0 2
  20470 1 0 0
   2034 1 0 1
     14 1 0 2
   4456 1 1 0
    201 1 1 1
    404 1 2 0
     14 1 2 1
     16 1 3 0
   3622 2 0 0
    152 2 0 1
    624 2 1 0
      6 2 1 1
     31 2 2 0
      1 2 3 0
    143 3 0 0
      1 3 0 1
     38 3 1 0
      1 3 2 0
```

So empty rows are quite common in 17-clue puzzles (65.6%). Empty columns are equally common, of course. The reason for the asymmetry in the results above is that the initial list of 17-clue puzzles is presented in minlex form. Empty boxes are less common (9.7%) but still easy to find. There is one puzzle that has 3 empty rows and 2 empty columns!

```
..............1..2..3....4.............34..5..1..6...7...........4..5.3..7.8.2..1
```